# Why can't running exes and loaded dlls be deleted on Windows?

Tags: windows

I mean, what's the point? They're on system memory anyway.
I couldn't find any "official" docs that explains why Windows protects loaded objects (exe, dll and even ocx).

I'm guessing:

- Intended measure for security matter or against human error
- File system limitation

We can easily delete any file unless locked on Unix. This only hinders ux in my opinion. Hoogle "how to delete dll" if you need proof. Many people suffered and i'm one of them.

Any words that Microsoft mention about this?
Any way to disable this "protection"? (probably isn't and never will be because Windows!)

Comment: Not "on system memory".  The OS creates a memory-mapped file on the executable file.  Code is paged into RAM only when necessary.  The MMF inevitably also locks the file.

Comment: Alright, alright. It was my mistake to say system memory. There's virtual memory too, and my point wasn't which specific type of memory.

Comment: what im saying was that programs in file system must not have anything to do with anything once they're loaded. In that case, the system should map  to virtual space, which Linux kernel does actually with swap.

Comment: Looked for the answer for myself. A running program is indeed an open file in Linux (it appears on lsof output). It's only that Linux supports lazy unlink of open files, like -l option in mount.

Comment: And windows on the other hand, there's no such operation thus telling the user that the file cannot be deleted. Although, windows allows renaming(moving) of a running program. Lots of confusion, this windows thing is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They're on system memory anyway.

No, they're not. Individual pages are loaded on demand, and discarded from RAM when the system decides that they've been unused for a while and the RAM could be put to better use for another process (or another page in this process).

Which means that, effectively, the EXE file is open for as long as the process is running, and the DLL file is open until/unless the process unloads the DLL, in both cases so pages can be loaded/reloaded as needed.